# Взаимосвязь полей date, обработчик события date

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, дата, события

Есть два html поля date, дата отправки и дата прибытия. Время, затраченное на путь, лежит в бд. Это не главное, можно засунуть его в сессию или еще куда. Как устроить взаимосвязь в реальном времени, что бы выбирая дату отправки, дата прибытия тут же высчитывалась исходя из даты отправки и времени в пути? Отчасти это вопрос так же затрагивает вопрос "как повесить обработчик на событие изменения даты"?

Answer (score 0):

getEndDate высчитывает разницу между выбранной датой в инпуте и количеством дней которые будут затрачены на путь

```js
var travelDays = 7// количество дней пути которое будете брать из БД

function getEndDate(startDate) {
   startDate = startDate.split('-')
   var year = startDate[0],
       month = startDate[1] - 1, // -1 потому-что отсчёт месяцев начинается с 0
       day = startDate[2]
   var date = new Date(year, month, day);
   date.setDate((date.getDate() + 1) + travelDays);
   console.log(date)
   return date;
}

var arrival = document.getElementById('arrival')
arrival.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  getEndDate(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<input type='date' id='arrival'>
```